# difference between m way tree and m way search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I tried finding the difference between m way tree and the m way search tree. Most resources only tells about m way search tree and end up being on B tree or B+ trees.

**My doubts are:-**

- Is it analogous to the binary tree and binary search tree?
- I read somewhere that m way trees don't have any particular order and
  every node has to be filled fully before moving to the new node.(complete
  tree)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it analogous to the binary tree and binary search tree?

Yes

> m way trees don't have any particular order

This is true

> and every node has to be filled fully before moving to the new node.(complete tree)

Something like this describes a step in an algorithm, and has little to do with the data structure itself: nothing is "moving" in a data structure.

## Definitions

In short: an m-way tree puts no conditions on the values stored in the nodes, while an m-way search tree does.

[Reva Freedman, associate professor at Northern Illinois University](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/%7Efreedman) has notes on [Multiway Trees](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/%7Efreedman/340/340notes/340multi.htm) where four terms are defined in succession, each time indicating which *additional* requirements apply for the next term:

1. *multi way tree*,
2. *m-way tree*
3. *m-way search tree*
4. *B-tree of order m*

> ## Multiway Trees
>
> A **multiway tree** is a tree that can have more than two children. A
> multiway tree of order m (or an **m-way tree**) is one in which a tree can
> have *m* children.
>
> As with the other trees that have been studied, the nodes in an m-way
> tree will be made up of key fields, in this case *m*-1 key fields, and
> pointers to children.
>
> To make the processing of m-way trees easier, some type of order will
> be imposed on the keys within each node, resulting in a multiway
> search tree of order *m* ( or an **m-way search tree**). By definition an
> m-way search tree is a m-way tree in which:
>
> - Each node has *m* children and *m*-1 key fields
> - The keys in each node are in ascending order.
> - The keys in the first *i* children are smaller than the *i<sup>th</sup>* key
> - The keys in the last *m-i* children are larger than the *i<sup>th</sup>* key
>
> M-way search trees give the same advantages to m-way trees that binary
> search trees gave to binary trees - they provide fast information
> retrieval and update. However, they also have the same problems that
> binary search trees had - they can become unbalanced, which means that
> the construction of the tree becomes of vital importance.
>
> #### B-Trees
>
> An extension of a multiway search tree of order *m* is a **B-tree of
> order *m***. This type of tree will be used when the data to be
> accessed/stored is located on secondary storage devices because they
> allow for large amounts of data to be stored in a node.
>
> A B-tree of order *m* is a multiway search tree in which:
>
> - The root has at least two subtrees unless it is the only node in the tree.
> - Each nonroot and each nonleaf node have at most *m* nonempty children and at least *m*/2 nonempty children.
> - The number of keys in each nonroot and each nonleaf node is one less than the number of its nonempty children.
> - All leaves are on the same level.

Comment: Could you let me know whether this answered your question?